# Regex between < >

Tags: php, regex

I have a string that looks like:

```
Pretext<thecontentineed>
```

I' trying to write a regex that will pull "thecontentineed" from that string using preg_match

I've tried:

```
$string = "Pretext<thecontentineed>";    
preg_match("/<.*?>/" , $string, $output);
```

But that returns an empty array.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$string = "Pretext<thecontentineed>";    
preg_match("/<(.*?)>/" , $string, $output);
```

You forgot the ()

Answer (score 3):

```
if (preg_match('/<(.*?)>/', $string, $output)) {
    echo $output[1];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$string = "Pretext<thecontentineed>";
preg_match("/\<([^>]+)\>/" , $string, $output);
print_r($output);
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified any capturing groups with `()`:

```
preg_match('/<(.*)?>/', $string, $matches);
```

The () instruct the regex pattern to 'capture' whatever matches within the brackets, and store them into the $matches array.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (preg_match('/Pretext<(.*?)>/', $string, $output)) {
    echo $output[1];
}
```